Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi } \frac{x}{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx$
Could someone help me evaluate this? I am not getting a lead. Numerically the value is around $2.80723 + 1.73497 i$.
$$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{x}{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx$$

There is no closed formula for $\int {\frac{\sin x}{x}} dx$, so I guess there's no closed formula for $\int {\frac{x}{a+b \cos(x)}}dx$ either, so we are looking here at a numerical problem

I do get the value $\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}} \pi$ for the integral. Sadly, I do not have time to write my approach down at the moment. If nobody answers, I might try later today.

@Dominique: You do get an exact answer by the symmetry $x\mapsto\pi-x$ (since we have a definite integral here).

Using King's Rule:
$$\begin{align*}\int_0^{\pi } \frac{x}{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx&=\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\pi -x}{1+(1+i) \cos (2 (\pi -x))} \, dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\pi }{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx-\int_0^{\pi } \frac{x}{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx\end{align*}$$
and then from above equation:
$$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{x}{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi } \frac{\pi }{1+(1+i) \cos (2 x)} \, dx=\frac{i \pi ^2}{2 \sqrt{-1+2 i}}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}} \pi ^2$$

Perfect. Thank you very much.
